# I can't access the routes in my fastapi app

Tags: python-3.x, docker, https, fastapi, reverse-proxy

I have a fastapi application deployed on top of a docker on a debian server. If I try to do http://1X.1XX.XX.8/docs (which is my server's IP) everything goes fine. IT colleagues have already defined an HTTPS domain for the server, which is https://predict.fakecompany.com.co. When I try to do https://predict.fakecompany.com.co then I get the root message of the fastapi application, however, when I do https://predict.fakecompany.com.co/docs then I get:

[image]

[image]

I've tried a lot of things but I don't know what to do anymore. I would appreciate any help or ideas. Thanks a lot.

The only thing I hope is that by trying to use the domain and the different paths of my fastapi application I will be able to access them. Also, I don't understand why Reason: DNS lookup failure for: 1X.1XX.1X.X:80docs appears when I think it should appear (I think) Reason: DNS lookup failure for: 1X.1XX.1X.X:80/docs

Comment: Looks like the proxy server is configured incorrectly. Share more information about your stack. Are you using NGINX, for example?